# Vue.js animations not working correctly

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, css-animations, vuejs2

I am using Vue 2 and attempting to include CSS animations on elements that are created and destroyed frequently. Below is an example of my code:

```js
  export default {
    name: 'MyElement',
    methods: {
      enterStart: function (el) {
        console.log('about to enter');
        el.classList.add('testing-enter');
      },
      enter: function (el) {
        console.log('entered');
      },
      leaveStart: function (el) {
        console.log('starting to leave!');
      },
      leave: function (el) {
        console.log('leaving!');
      },
    }
  };
```

```css
.testing-enter {
  animation: enter .2s;
}

.testing-leave {
  animation: leave .2s;
}

@keyframes enter {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes leave {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <transition
      @before-enter="enterStart"
      @enter="enter"
      @leave="leaveStart"
      @leave-active="leave"
      appear
    >
      <div>My element is here!</div>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>
```

First off, none of this works unless I include `appear` in my `<transition ...>` element. I know that this makes the transition happen on initial rendering, but I want them to happen any time the element is created or destroyed.

Next, in my console. I can see `enterStart` and `enter` both run, but `leaveStart` and `leave` never run, even when the elements are destroyed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i've just created this codepen for test [link](http://codepen.io/marceloch2/pen/oZGpPd?editors=1000)

Comment: @marceloch2 thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The element inside the transition needs a state (show or hide). Also your transition needs a name that must much the transition in the CSS and it should be named with

> name="transitionName"

e.g:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
    return {
      showThisElement: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleShow: function() {
      this.showThisElement = !this.showThisElement
    }
  }
});
```

```css
    .testing-enter-active {
      animation: enter .2s;
    }

    .testing-leave-active {
      animation: leave .2s;
    }

    @keyframes enter {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(0);
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1);
      }
    }
    @keyframes leave {
      0% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1);
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(0);
      }
    }
```

```html
   <div id="app">
  
  <div @click="toggleShow">Show/Hide</div>
  
  <transition 
    name="testing">

    <div v-if="showThisElement">My element is here!</div>

  </transition>
</div>
```

In the codepen, click on 'show/hide' to toggle the transition.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WpZPJp

Comment: Thank you for the working example. So the fact that I need a toggle throws a wrench in my plans. In my app, this component is a small child item of a larger collection component. It doesn't have any buttons that hide or show it, it simply just gets rendered in a `v-for...` in the parent container component. Do you have any advice as to how I could still get the animation behavior to fit in with how my item is rendered?

Answer (score 1):

**Problem solved!**

So I took out the `transition` from the individual component and created a `transition-group` instead around the container component that rendered them.

Then, after a bit more reading I realized I wanted to add the `mode="out-in"` field to my `transition-group` so that the leaving components fully animate before the new ones are rendered.

I also looked at the HTML when the animations were supposed to be happening to see what classes Vue added. It looks like Vue added `v-enter-active, v-enter-to,` and `v-leave-to`. Instead of customizing any names I just stuck with those classes and added my animations to them in the styling.

Hopefully if anybody else wants a similar effect this helps them decrease their stress levels a bit...